# Best way to connect Lightswitch and BizTalk via web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, biztalk, visual-studio-lightswitch, biztalk-2010

I have a database that doing simple CRUD and connected via BizTalk Server 2010. Since Lightswitch is very simple and looks fits for that CRUD operation, I want to introduce Lightswitch for the operational staff here.

(I am not an expert in both technologies) the problem is, Lightswitch consumes WCF RIA Services. While BizTalk by default cannot expose such type of web services.

my question is :
what is the best type of web-service should I expose from BizTalk in order to be consumed by Lightswitch?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option is to throw a proxy service in between.  You can take a BizTalk-generated WCF endpoint and wrap that service call with another service that exposes the DomainService that LightSwitch asks for.

For example, see this LightSwitch team blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2010/10/22/how-to-create-a-ria-service-wrapper-for-odata-source.aspx